# Explicit int type as parameter

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Is it possible to write a function as:

```
void func(uint64_t val) {template <typename T>
```

void call_with(std::function<void(T)> f, T val) {
f(val);
}

int main() {
auto print = [](int x) { std::cout << x; };
call_with(print, 42);
}}

where a compile time error is generated if it's called with any other integer type than `uint64_t`, without modifying my `#pragma` warnings?

ie:

```
uint32_t x = 0;
func(x) {…} // Error!
func(uint64_t(x)) {…} // Succes!
```

Comment: So, you want to prevent `func(1)`?

Comment: This seems like an unusual requirement; passing a smaller integer type causes no loss of precision or data and is very well-defined. For passing by value, it's making a copy, so there's no modification issues. What is your reason behind requiring exactly the same bit width?

Comment: @peachykeen I've got two id's which handles a caching mechanism, whereas one happen to be 32bit and one 64bit. In this case, it'd be conveniant to get a compilation error if the 32bit id is passed to the 64bit parameter. (I am aware I can make explicit types.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overload the function with a function template. The function template will be a better match for all argument types except `uint64_t`. You can define the function template, so that it will create an error if used.

```
void func(uint64_t val) { ... }

template <typename T>
void func(T)
{
    static_assert(false, "argument type is not uint64_t");
}
```

With C++11 you can use the following template:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T&&) = delete;
```

Comment: @ViktorSehr why did you mark this one?  this is not what you want, the correct answer is Lunchians, and this is a duplicate question...

Comment: I dont remember exactly why as it is many years ago, but as the other one said linker error I suppose I preferred a compile time error.

Answer (score 4):

This would work:

```
template< typename T >
void func( T param );

template<>
void func<uint64_t>( uint64_t param )
{
}
```

You'll get a linker error (close enough). Sample: http://ideone.com/5ft4F

Comment: Haha, thanks man, that you notified me for this! :) Appreciated! I saw, that it does not compile, but I didn't see the error at first sight and I didn't have time to see what's wrong at the moment. +1, that's what was missing in my answer.

Comment: +1 so far. I'll mark it correct if a better solution isnt found

Comment: @KirilKirov I was actually attempting to steer you in the right direction, but you deleted the answer (wouldn't have added one otherwise).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - yep, I got that and I really appreciate it.